# JSP table row button to call servlet

Tags: jsp, button, servlets, html-table, row

My JSP table is listing many rows with a button "Details" for each row like below : -

[Message_ID is unique for each row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dks63.png)

The Details button when clicked, will call a servlet with the unique Message_ID and a pop-up  jsp page will display the json of the message.

How can I pass the unique Message_ID of each row to servlet ?

Thanks & Regards
Saswata Mandal

Comment: Please note , that the rows of the table are NOT instances of any java bean or model class. The table column values are text returned from database.

Comment: Can I use hidden form fields to get the column values of the row for which the Details button is clicked ? Please guide how to do this with Hidden Form fields !!